# Is it possible to make a text input with suggestions based on what you type?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, dropdown

How would I go about having a drop down appear based off of what I type into a text field, where the selected option would 'write' itself into the text field? For example if I was asked what my favourite colour was and I began by typing 'dar' a dropdown would appear with options 'dark red', 'dark blue', 'dark green' etc. however if I typed in 'dark g' a dropdown would appear with only the option 'dark green'? Think of it kind of like a text input that eliminates choices off a dropdown, however selecting an option in the dropdown inputs them into the text field.

This is my code at the moment (although I assume I'll need JS?):

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Name Of Gear">
                <input type="number" class="amount" maxlength="4" placeholder="Amount" max="999">
```

Comment: Is it possible...yes. Is how to do it too broad a question for this site...also yes. Search the web for scripts that do this with terms like *"autocomplete"* or *"typeahead"*

Comment: are you allowed to use 3rd party libraries, or you must do it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to autocomplete a entire dictionary, this is to slow.
But if you just want to autocomplete some words (like "green", "red", etc.) this should do it.

In your HMTL you need a input and a div.
The input is for typing and the div presents the suggestions.

```
<input id="input" oninput="findSuggestions('input', 'suggestions')">
<div id="suggestions"></div>
```

So if you type, a function will be called.
This function will go through an array with all the suggestions in it.

```
var arySuggestions = ["Alarm", "Already" , "Ballon"] // This is where all you suggestions go

function findSuggestions(strInputId, strSuggestionsDivId) { 
    var objInput = document.getElementById(strInputId)
    var strInput = objInput.value // get the current text

    var objSuggestionsDiv = document.getElementById(strSuggestionsDivId)

    if (strInput.length > 0) {
        objSuggestionsDiv.innerHTML = ""; // empty the suggestion div, just in case
        var objList = document.createElement("ul");

        for (var i = 0; i < arySuggestions.length; i++) {
            var word = arySuggestions[i]
            var wordPart = word.substring(0,strInput.length)
            if (word.length > strInput.length && wordPart === strInput) { // check if the words are matching
                // if they do create a list entry
                var objListEntity = document.createElement("li");
                objListEntity.setAttribute("onclick", "complete('" + word + "', '" + strInputId + "', '" + strSuggestionsDivId + "');");
                objListEntity.innerHTML = word;
                objList.appendChild(objListEntity);
            }
        }
        // show the suggestionList
        objSuggestionsDiv.appendChild(objList);
    } else {
        objSuggestionsDiv.innerHTML = ""; // empty the suggestion div
    }
}
```

And there is a second function. So that when you click on the suggestion it will fill it in:

```
function complete(strComplete, strInputId, strSuggestionsDivId) {
    document.getElementById(strInputId).value = strComplete;
    document.getElementById(strSuggestionsDivId).innerHTML = ""; // empty the suggestion div
}
```

If you want the suggestions to follow your cursor you will probably need some css.

Hope this helps

Comment: This isn't working for me - I've tried it in my code and literally just copied/pasted what you've posted in a jsfiddle and neither works, are you sure it's working properly? Thanks :)

Comment: I just copy/pasted it into a new document and it works fine for me. What kind of error do you get? Try to write a capital A and see if you get "Alarm" and "Already" as a suggestion, please :)

Comment: Try to use the js inline instead of external and see what happens

Comment: Still doesn't work for me... really strange.
Also I've found an example of what I'm looking for if it makes it more obvious what I want: https://codepen.io/Rio517/pen/NPLbpP - does the code you wrote achieve this? And can it be reused for different inputs with different answers?

Comment: It doesn't show you all possibilities from the beginning. But as you start typing it shows all the matching ones. Of course it doesn't look as pretty as the example, because i didn't do any css work. Maybe try to run the code on codepen. Still works for me. ^^